# I am trying to insert DatePicker component to my project but getting an error

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS, sorry if this sounds off

this is the error showen in console when compiling :

### react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default is not a function or its return value is not iterable

this is the piece of code to insert the DatePicker component :

```
import React from 'react'
import useState from 'react'
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

const Example = () => {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    return (
      <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
    );
  };
export default Example
```

Answer (score 0):

`import React, {useState} from 'react';`

instead of

```
import React from 'react'
import useState from 'react'
```

useState is not default-exported function.

Comment: the problem is resolved easily :) thank you